# jQuery RadioButtonList onchange not firing on postback

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of asp:RadioButtonList defined in my code and both are Yes/No radio buttons. If I select Yes on the first one the second needs to be cleared and disabled. If No is selected the 2nd one is enabled again.

The issue I am having is that on postback the jQuery onchange is not firing.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ctl00_MainContent_rblEmploymentStatus input').change(function () {
        if ((this).value == 1) {
            // Disable Q3
            $('[id *= ctl00_MainContent_rblEmploymentAspiration2]').find('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            });

            $("#ctl00_MainContent_rblEmploymentAspiration2 input:radio").attr('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $("#ctl00_MainContent_rblEmploymentAspiration2 input:radio").attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<tr>
    <td align="left">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblEmploymentStatus" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="left">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblEmploymentAspiration2" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How do I make sure this event is called at all times? Thanks.

Comment: It would be very helpful if we could see your html

Comment: I never do ASP, but if it work like JEE, are you sure all your DOM is write at the page load ? Does `$('body').on('change', '#ctl00_MainContent_rblEmploymentStatus input', function() {...})` work ?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Added the HTML